# Laravel - Authentication issue with Admin & Front

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I am working on an application which contains its `front end` and `admin panel`
How do I implement separate authentication for them?

Let's say for ex. Front-end authentication is working fine I'm using the standard `auth()->attempt()` but what about admin panel I think I can not use the same for the admin panel,
once if I logged in from front-end then if I check `dd(auth()->user())` in admin area somewhere but it returns the front end users data.

In short, I have been stuck in two Authentication can someone tell me the logic "How do I implement two separate authentication one for admin panel and for front end"

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Javed Baloch You can use Multi Auth laravel.
https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Comment: @MayurPanchal Kindly suggest how can we use the same solution for Laravel 8.x version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using laravel inbuilt authentication method, you can use custom guards

In your `auth.php` file add custom guard

```
'guards' => [
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'customers',
    ],
]
```

and access by

```
Auth::guard('customer')->attempt() function.
```

for more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#adding-custom-guards